# Does the twitter search API support a wildcard like q=*?

Tags: twitter

I want to search for all popular tweets with language german. I tried the following query (`q=*` is encoded as `q=%2A`)

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%2A&lang=de&result_type=popular&with_twitter_user_id=true&include_entities=true
```

This seems to return results, but 
I have found no documentation that twitter search api supports wildcards. So I'm not sure if the results returned by that query are the one I want. I only found this example from the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent
```

which seems to imply that one has to use an empty query string `q=` instead of a wildcard. However if I try

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&lang=de&result_type=popular&with_twitter_user_id=true&include_entities=true
```

I do get an error "Query parameters are missing". 
So how can I search for all popular tweets with language german if a wildcard (`q=*`) are not supported and an empty query (`q=`) is also not allowed?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If the query string weren't limited to 500 characters it may be plausible to create a long or string to include everything. I may try this with alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query string such as this to search all tweets which use roman alphabet languages:

> e OR t OR n OR o OR a OR i OR r OR s OR h OR l OR d OR c OR f OR u OR m OR y OR g OR p OR b OR v OR w OR k OR q OR j OR x OR z OR 0 OR 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9

Note I have not tested to see if rich media-only tweets, such as videos or images with no captions, are included in the results.